# Individual Background Images for Individual Divs

Tags: html, css, class, background-image

For a current project of mine, I'm working on a website for a clan of sorts. They've asked me to create a grid of games that they play, and I seem to be struggling with that.

Each individual `div` considsts of a `background-image` and a `p` element for the title of the game. Currently, for every different game, I have to create a new `div` and a new class in my style sheet, and I only end up changing the `left-margin` a bit and changing that background image's filepath. It feels like a bit of a waste of time to me.

The code is as follows:

(HTML)

```
<div id="content" align="center">
<div class="content-box">

    <div class="content-box-game-one">
        <p>Just Cause 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box-game-two">
        <p>War Thunder</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box-game-three">
        <p>Borderlands 2</p>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="content-box-game-four">
        <p>Heroes and Generals</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box-game-five">
        <p>Grand Theft Auto V</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box-game-six">
        <p>Dirty Bomb</p>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="content-box-game-seven">
        <p>PayDay 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box-game-eight">
        <p>Team Fortress 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box-game-nine">
        <p>Coming soon...</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

(CSS)

```
    #content {
    margin-top: 3px;
}

    .content-box {
        width: 1150px;
        height: 100%;
    }

        .content-box-game-one {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 80px;

            background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/ZZtELB6.png');
            background-size: 400px;
        }

        .content-box-game-two {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;

            background-image: url('http://war-thunder-hack.marioapps.net/assets/cheatmp/images/background.jpg');
            background-size: 400px;
        }

        .content-box-game-three {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;

            background-image: url('http://www.hardcoregamer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/borderlands2.jpg');
            background-size: 400px;
        }

        .content-box-game-four {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 80px;

            background-image: url('http://www.gamewallpapers.com/previews_480x300/wallpaper_heroes_and_generals_01.jpg');
            background-size: 400px;
        }

        .content-box-game-five {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;

            background-image: url('http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/audio/video/2012/11/15/1352984366518/Grand-Theft-Auto-V-005.jpg');
            background-size: 400px;
        }

        .content-box-game-six {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;

            background-image: url('https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/article-1354195970386-16454a86000005dc-11033_636x353.jpg');
            background-size: 400px;
        }

        .content-box-game-seven {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 80px;

            background-image: url('http://www.gamechup.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/payday-2-featured-1.jpg');
            background-size: 400px;
        }

        .content-box-game-eight {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;

            background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/59/TF2_Group.jpg');
            background-size: 400px;
        }

        .content-box-game-nine {
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;

            background-image: url('http://www.exoticindia.com/religious/sfa47.jpg');
            background-size: 400px;
        }



            .content-box p {
                margin-top: 80px;
                font-family: Lobster;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 30px;
                color: white;
            }
```

Is there anyway I can just create one class on my stylesheet and have it so that the background image will change? Any other ways around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all other properties are same other than background-image you can create one general `class` like:

```
.content-box-game {
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 80px;
        background-size: 400px;
    }
```

Then you only need to specify a `background-image` property in your other classes.

```
.content-box-game-one{
        background-image: url('http://www.hardcoregamer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/borderlands2.jpg');
}
```

**Add both classes to your div**

```
<div class="content-box-game content-box-game-one">
      <p>Borderlands 2</p>
</div>
```